# ReactJS: drag and drop between multiple lists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm newbie in ReactJS.
I'm having a component similar like this:

```
<Section/>
   <Lesson/>
   <Lesson/>
   <Lesson/>
<Section/>
   <Lesson/>
   <Lesson/>
<Section/>
   <Lesson/>
   <Lesson/>
   <Lesson/>
```

How can I drag and drop Lesson among these Sections?
I found a library help with this: https://github.com/bevacqua/react-dragula, but I'm a little bit confused of `ref` Section ReactDOM

Comment: About react, you can watch nice course here: https://egghead.io/courses/react-fundamentals, and about react keys you can read here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#keys

Comment: For Drag and Drop you could also check out the React DND library, it's pretty well supported.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at Dragula example. They are using React's feature called [ref Callback Attribute](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute).

From the documentation:

> React supports a special attribute that you can attach to any component. The ref attribute can be a callback function, and this callback will be executed immediately after the component is mounted. The referenced component will be passed in as a parameter, and the callback function may use the component immediately, or save the reference for future use (or both).

Comment: hi @luboskrnac, thanks for the Document. I'm having trouble in problem: How can I get all Sections' Ref, because I just know the way to get ref of a Section by using React's ref callback feature